# How to use the "Scan QR code" quick tile to my app's advantage?

Tags: qr-code, android-13

In Android 13, we have a new quick tile "Scan QR code". When we scan a QR with it, it takes us to the relevant app or if there are multiple apps that supports this QR data type it lets us choose and navigates to that app.

For example, if we scan an UPI QR code, it shows us all the apps that support scanning UPI code like GPay, PayTM, PhonePe, etc.

Likewise I have a set of QR formats which is used only by my app. How do I tell this quick tile to pick up my app when scanning this QR?